# Scipy - A better way to avoid manually loop when matrix is sparse

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, scipy, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression

Logistic regression's objective function is

[image: objective]

and the gradient is

[image: gradient]

where `w` is a scipy's csr sparse matrix with dim n-by-1.

My question is, when I have one scipy's csr sparse matrix and one numpy array, `X_train` and `y_train` respectively. (Each row of `X_train` is `x_i`, each element of `y_train` is `y_i`)
Is there a better way to calculate the gradient without using manully for loop?

For further information, I'm implementing [large scale logistic regression](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/courses/optml2014/lr.pdf). Therefore the performance is important.

Thanks.

**Update 5/19 (Add my current code)**

Thanks for @Jaime's reminding, here is my code. I basically want to see if there is a better way to implement `gradient(X, y, w)`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn import datasets
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy import sparse

eta = 0.01
xi  = 0.1
C   = 1

X_train, y_train = datasets.load_svmlight_file('lr/datasets/a9a')
X_test, y_test   = datasets.load_svmlight_file('lr/datasets/a9a.t', n_features=X_train.shape[1])

def gradient(X, y, w):
  # w should be a col vector
  summation = w
  for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    exp_i = np.exp( y[i] *  X.getrow(i).dot(w)[0, 0] )
    summation = summation - (y[i] / (1 + exp_i)) * X.getrow(i).T

  return summation

def hes_mul(X, D, s):
  # w and s should be a col vector
  # should return a col vector
  return s + C * X.T.dot( D.dot( X.dot(s) ) )


def cg(X, y, w):
  # gradF is col vector, so all of these are col vectors
  gradF = gradient(X, y, w)
  s = sparse.csr_matrix( np.zeros(X_train.shape[1]) ).T
  r = -1 * gradF
  d = r

  D = []
  for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    exp_i = np.exp( (-1) * y[i] * w.T.dot(X.getrow(i).T)[0, 0] )
    D.append(exp_i / ((1 + exp_i) ** 2))
  D = sparse.diags(D, 0)

  while True:

    r_norm = np.sqrt((r.data ** 2).sum())
    print r_norm
    print np.sqrt((gradF.data ** 2).sum())

    if r_norm <= xi * np.sqrt((gradF.data ** 2).sum()):
      return s

    hes_mul_d = hes_mul(X, D, d)

    alpha = (r_norm ** 2) / d.T.dot( hes_mul_d )[0, 0]

    s = s + alpha * d

    r = r - alpha * hes_mul_d

    beta = (r.data ** 2).sum() / (r_norm ** 2)

    d = r + beta * d


w = sparse.csr_matrix( np.zeros(X_train.shape[1]) ).T
s = cg(X_train, y_train, w)
```

Comment: What is `w` in your formulas? If you provide your current code, someone will help you speed it up. Requests for having code written for you without showing what you have tried are usually not well received.

Comment: Hi, @Jaime, thanks for your reminding. I just added my current code. `w` is a column vector, but in csr format.